# Perturbation of the system $x_i - 1 = \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij} x_j e^{-x_j}$

Tags: functional-analysis, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

For a numerical optimization algorithm that I'm currently developing for my research, I am facing the following challenge for which any help is very much appreciated!

Let $w_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}_+$ be constants and consider the following system.

$$x_i - 1 = \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij} x_j e^{-x_j}, \hspace{1cm} i=1,\dots,n,$$

with $x_i > 0$. Assume that the $w_{ij}$'s are such that a unique solution exists and let this solution be $x^*$.

Now, if we perturb the $w_{ij}$'s, e.g., $w'_{ij} = w_{ij} + \varepsilon$, can we bound the region in which the new solution $x'$ must lie? That is, can we find an $\eta(\varepsilon)$ such that:

$$|x^*_i - x'_i| \leq \eta(\varepsilon).$$

Informally stated, given that we change the system's parameters a little bit, can we say something about the 'distance' from the old to the new solution?

More generally, what if we perturb the system such that $|w'_{ij} - w_{ij}| < \varepsilon$ for all $i,j$?

Thanks once more.

Comment: If we leave out the exponential factors I think you can get such a bound if the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) of the matrix $w$ is <1. Including the exponentials, I speculate that you would need some bounds on $w$. Are there bounds on $w$ in your application?

Comment: Yes, there are bounds on $w_{ij}$, i.e., one may assume that $w_{ij} \in [l_{ij}, u_{ij}]$. Is that what you meant? Or do you require something stronger? Thanks.

Comment: What may be of interest: I already considered using a (local) Lipschitz constant of $\partial x / \partial w_{ij}$ by using the implicit function theorem, but this seems inconceivable since no analytical expression for the inverse of $\partial F / \partial x$ exists (it is nonsingular though, for the values of $w$ that I'm considering). Here $F_i(x) = x_i - 1 - \sum_j w_{ij} x_j e^{-x_j}$.

Comment: What are $l_{ij}, u_{ij}$ ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. All I tried to emphasise was that for all the problem instances I am considering the $w_{ij}$'s come from certain known intervals. In your first comment you noted that one might need bounds on $w$. But, then, I wonder in terms of what these bounds are given? For example, in terms of $n$? Or in terms of $\|W\|$ for example? Where $W$ is the matrix with elements $w_{ij}$.

Comment: I figured that without the exponential factors, I can solve for $x$ if $W+1$ is invertible. Of course, this does not apply with the exponentials included, but it suggests that the magnitude of $W$ matters. Without knowing the nature of the optimization problem it's hard to say much.